# Modeling threshold effects

Tags: mixed-model, threshold

First, let me give some context for my question.

I'm working on a project in which our research team implemented a workshop intervention at a number of different departments at my university.  Each department that received the intervention also had a matched control department.  We obtained several different measures from professors and staff in these departments at three timepoints: before the intervention and at two follow-up time points.

To examine the effects of our intervention on our various outcome measures, we are using the following model using the lme4 package, where pair is a code indicating the department pair the respondent was from, dept is a code indicating the department the respondent was in, and person is a code for each respondent:

mod <- lmer(outcome ~ condition * time + (1|pair) + (1|dept) + (1|person), data = d)

We also have records on the percent of people that attended the workshop within the intervention departments.  Using these attendance data, we could fit the following model:

mod <- lmer(outcome ~ attendance * time + (1|pair) + (1|dept) + (1|person), data = d)

However, we would like to go one step further by estimating the attendance threshold required for the intervention to affect the outcome.

I've reached a bit of a blind alley in terms of how to test for threshold effects.  Does anyone have any ideas on how we might go about this?

Comment: Could you create an "attendance" variable that's either the percentage of a "full class" or the percentage of the department that attended? Also, is "(1|pair)" sufficient? I wish I knew enough to make an answer, but I'll bump the question up.

Comment: Wayne, yes, we do have an "attendance" variable for each department.  The question is how to obtain an estimated threshold for "attendance" beyond which "attendance" is predicted to affect the outcome.  I will update my question with more of these details.